# Why can't the local teamcity build agent access the server

Tags: java, windows, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I'm having trouble with the local build agent on teamcity - it can't register with the server. Remote agents are registering successfully. Here's the agent log, the server logs say nothing about it.

```
[2013-09-23 12:20:43,739]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Registering on server http://localhost, AgentDetails{Name='name', AgentId=null, BuildId=null, AgentOwnAddress='null', AlternativeAddresses=[192.168.56.1, 10.55.72.133], Port=9090, Version='27540', PluginsVersion='27540-md5-2b35d17be053845ad7c8e61930f772f0', AvailableRunners=[Ant, dotnet-tools-dupfinder, dotnet-tools-inspectcode, Duplicator, FxCop, gradle-runner, Inspection, Ipr, jb.nuget.installer, jb.nuget.pack, jb.nuget.publish, jetbrains.dotNetGenericRunner, jetbrains.mspec, jetbrains_powershell, JPS, Maven2, MSBuild, MSTest, NAnt, NUnit, rake-runner, simpleRunner, sln2003, VS.Solution], AvailableVcs=[perforce, mercurial, jetbrains.git, tfs, svn, cvs], AuthorizationToken=''} 
[2013-09-23 12:20:47,796]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Call http://localhost/RPC2 buildServer.registerAgent3: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset 
[2013-09-23 12:20:47,797]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Connection to TeamCity server is probably lost. Will be trying to restore it. Take a look at logs/teamcity-agent.log for details (unless you're using custom logging).
```

There are no relevant entries in the Event Viewer logs.

The teamcity agent is using the same version of Java as the server.

Comment: Try to looks at the Agent log, not Server log.

Comment: @AlexanderDoroshenko This is the agent log.

Answer (score 0):

Could be something with your host file if its trying to use `localhost`.

Try adjusting the Local Agent to connect to the same IP / Port that the remote agents are using and to set the Local Agent's IP to be that of the Machine.